# SQL: year to end of the month?

Tags: sql

I have a dataset in the format of: `Date Amount` such as:

```
Date       Amount
2018-01    100
2018-02    200
2018-03    300
```

I want the sum year to date at the end of each month resulting in:

```
Date       Amount
2018-01    100
2018-02    300 (100+200)
2018-03    600 (100+200+300)
```

How do I go about referencing the previous year-to-date sum in the previous row?

Comment: will you have date of only 1 year ?

Comment: which sql are you using ms sql, mysql etc

Comment: @irfandar I will be using oracle db

Comment: @SudiptaMondal the rolling total will start on jan of every year, i will have multiple years of data

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a window function:

```
select date,
       sum(amount) over (order by date) as so_far
from the_table
order by date;
```

The above is ANSI standard SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Running Total for this.

```
SELECT 
  Date,
  SUM (Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) AS RunningAmount
FROM Table1
Order by Date asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OVER` clause for that. Try as below.

Use `PARTITION BY DATEPART(yy, Date)` if you want to separate cumulative total for each year as below.

```
SELECT Date, Amount, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(yy, Date) ORDER BY DATEPART(mm, Date)) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM Table
```

Or if you want to have cumulative total for all years then remove `PARTITION BY DATEPART(yy, Date)` part. Just order by is enough.

```
SELECT Date, Amount, SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM Table
```

Refer this for more information. [Producing a moving average and cumulative total](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-producing-a-moving-average-and-cumulative-total)

Answer (score 0):

Other option would to use a correlated subquery :

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t1.amount) from table t1 where t1.date <= t.date) as amount
from table t;
```

This would work almost in all *DBMS*.

Comment: thank you, how do I go about separating cumulative total for each year as seen on Karan's answer but in the subquery way?